# It's possible to find the amount of data used in Wi-Fi

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi

1. I am developing an app in which I need to scans WiFi network and display the list of all connected devices.

I find the solution for  device detection.

2. But I need how much amount of data used from Wi-Fi network?
   I don't know it's possible or not.

Any one known about my 2nd requirement.

Thanks for your help. Any suggestions/comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible

```
long wifiUsageByte = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
```

Comment: I want to get data usage of all the devices connected from my network.